# Что лучше использовать для работы с dbf из java?

Tags: java

Подскажите, что лучше использовать для работы с dbf из java.
нашел несколько вариантов, пытаюсь выбрать:

1. xBaseJ
2. javadbf-0.4.0
3. JDBF 1.0
4. stels_dbf
5. HXTT DBF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте HXTT DBF. Потому что коммерческий, поддерживаемый продукт.

Comment: большое спасибо, думал вопрос уже утонул навсегда

Comment: А почему, если коммерческий, так сразу и лучший? Разве  мало  прекрасных некоммерческих продуктов? И наоборот.

Comment: mikillskegg, это как сравнивать Eclipse, Netbeans и IntelliJ IDEA. Первые два вроде бы не плохие, некоммерческие, но до IntelliJ IDEA им далековато. Коммерчески успешный продукт всегда лучше)