# Чем прочитать DBF в Java

Tags: java, dbf

Требуется прочитать информацию из небольшой dbf-таблицы. Есть какая-то простенькая библиотека для чтения из этого формата? делать полноценный JDBC не хочется - таблица на пару десятков строк. И поменять стандарт таблицы так же нельзя... Как можно прочитать данные с наименьшим количеством усилий?

Comment: http://www.autopark.ru/ASBProgrammerGuide/DBFSTRUC.HTM  что то мне подсказывает, что лучше не полагаться на "простенькие" библиотеки :)

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/65788/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%81-dbf-%D0%B8%D0%B7-java

Comment: HXTT DBF требует сервер для работы с БД.
javadbf-0.4.0 то что я хотел, но в нем не работает метод чтения содержимого таблиц. Количество строк находит верно, но при попытке чтения возвращает null
XbaseJ вроде то что нужно, пойду разбирать, спасибо!

Comment: Я сам сделал читалку и писалку dbf. В инете либо всё платное, либо нерабочее. Формат dbf не такой уж и сложный.

Comment: Собственно, XbaseJ мне подошел. Единственное, что он распространяется как исходники, а не jar-библиотека, но это мелочи